# In nextjs, does the code for "/api" routes end up in the browser at any point? If so Is there a way to force server-side-only execution?

Tags: environment-variables, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm just now realizing this behavior about nextjs env vars [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables), which is different from how nodejs apps are usually set up:

> Note: **.env files should be included in your repository**, and
>   .env*.local should be in .gitignore, as those files are intended to be
>   ignored. Consider .local files as a good place for secrets, and
>   non-local files as a good place for defaults.

So I'm thinking of restricting myself to using a secret available only at build-time, to be used inside a "backend" `/api` route.

But do `/api` routes even behave like true backends? Since nextjs is SSR *only when it has to be* (?), I presume this /api code can also end up in the browser, therefore exposing the secret? Is there a way to force code to only run server-side and not in-browser? I am new to SSR concepts. My "real" backend won't be up for a while. This is not a hugely important secret, but still. Thx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

API routes won't end up in the client bundle, so any code you put in `/pages/api` will stay hidden from the user. These routes are meant to be run exclusively on a server environment.

The same concept applies to `getStaticProps` which only runs on a server during build.

NextJS has a mechanism called "inlined environment variables". Any references to environment variables that start with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` will be automatically replaced with their values. So if your local/build/production machine has the variable `NEXT_PUBLIC_APPNAME` set, NextJS will replace references to `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPNAME` with the variable's value.

Alternatively you can define variables in an `.env` file. These will also be used by your application, and may end up in your client bundle if you reference them in any code that renders on the client (like the JSX in `pages/about.js`).

Conclusion: secrets should be added to `.env`, and only be referenced in server-side code like API routes and `getStaticProps`.

You may also be interested in this tool: https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/

It lets you verify that your server-side code stays out of the client bundle.

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: No problem! I added another caveat in my answer which you should check out. In short, it *is* possible to expose secrets if you're not careful.